# Mouse/keyboard macro program?

Tags: mouse, keyboard, macros

I need a program that can record mouse and keyboard input, however it needs to record a specific way. Most macro programs record the position your cursor is at using pixel coordinates, however this does not work for me. I want to create mouse macros for use within a first person game, and if you're familiar with those you know that your mouse is constantly reset to the middle of your screen. Because of this, using pixel coordinates for mouse macro recording causes you to spin around infinitely. Is there a program that instead records perhaps how much your mouse moves instead of where it moves to? Like instead of using pixel coordinates (1744,772) it would record difference compared to last keyframe (+12,-16)?

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not a free program, you may find that [Macro Express](https://www.macros.com/) will fit your requirements specific to the mouse.

From the help page within the program:

> Relative to Last Position
>
> This option instructs the macro to move the mouse cursor relative to
>   the last position of the cursor. In this case do not input new
>   coordinates, just the number of pixels for the mouse to move.

It is only one of the many mouse related options for recording or creating macros to perform tasks.

I did not check to determine if the relative mouse movement is specific to Pro or the non-Pro version.